# limits on aws federated users and policies

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am working on aws to back up my data. i want to choose following approach for backing up my data.

1. suppose i have n numbers of organizations and each organization has n number of departments and each department has n numbers of users.
2. i want to back up those organizations data based on organization > department >user structure.
3. now i have an iam user account and a bucket in aws s3.
4. i create a folder structure based on organization structure as

   first folder for organization > subfolder for department > child sub folder for users

e.g
organization name :ABC

department name : Developer

user name: testUser

so bucket folder structure on aws will be as

ABC/Developer/testUser/....

so here i show how i am managing organization's data on aws s3.

but now the point is i am allowing organizations users to put/get data to/from s3 on request.

after user's request i will generate federated user credentials for that user will policy which will allow user to put/get data to/from only users folder.

But my questions are:

Q 1. How many federated users can i generate. Is their is any limit for federated users?

Q 2. how many policies an IAM user can generate at a time?

Q 3. As my approach mentioned above their can be n number of federated users so can i generate n number of policies and applies those to federated user.

Thanks & Regerds

Amit Manchanda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the answer for this question

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=172258&tstart=0